# Suppose that G is a finite group of even order. Show that G must contain an element $a\ne e$ for which $a^2 = e$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group of even order. Show that $G$ must contain a non- identity element a for which $a^2 = e$.

Comment: Think about inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the collection of sets $\{g,g^{-1}\}$ with $g\in G$. Note that $a^2=e$ is equivalent to $a=a^{-1}$.

Comment: I am thinking about inverses and whether the number of elements that are different from their own inverses are even or odd but I'm having trouble putting it down on paper. Just need a more solid starting point I feel frustrated with it.

Comment: @Sammy.d That collection of sets gives you a partition of $G$. Such sets can have cardinality $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the group is finite having even order, the number of non identity elements is odd (excluding identity element).

Now every one of these non identity elements have a unique inverse . As the number of non identity elements are odd, one non identity element will be left out at the end after pairing up the elements and their inverses.

Since this last element cannot have it's  inverse same as that of any other element (it is a group), the inverse of that element will be itself ( that is a = a inverse).